# Array foreach or use for loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have array ...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [number1] => 0
            [value] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [number1] => 0
            [value] => 3
     
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [number1] => 0
            [value] => 11
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [number1] => 1
            [value] => 10
        )
 [4] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
                [number1] => 1
                [value] => 13
            )
```

current my code ...

```
$namearray=array();
foreach($myArray as $key => $value){
                if($value['number1']==0){
                        $namearray[0][]=$value['value'];
                }
               if($value['number1']==1){
                        $namearray[1][]=$value['value'];
                }
        }
print_r($namearray);
```

my code current output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 11
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 13
        )

)
```

How to use loop to replace `if $value['number1']==0` and `$value['number1']==1` ?
I maybe have more `number1` number!
I try to use for loop but not work ! It will not display anything.

Comment: Its not very clear what the desired array looks like, why is a `3` added to index `0` and another `3` added to index `1`? Both (the entries with id 1 and 2) have the same values for `number1` and `number2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `number1` value to select the index.

```
$namearray = [];
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    $index = $value['number1']; // get the index
    $namearray[$index][] = $value['value']; // use it
}
print_r($namearray);
```

ex:

```
$myArray = [
    ['id' => 1, 'number1' => 0, 'value' => 3],
    ['id' => 2, 'number1' => 0, 'value' => 3],
    ['id' => 3, 'number1' => 0, 'value' => 11],
    ['id' => 4, 'number1' => 1, 'value' => 10],
    ['id' => 5, 'number1' => 1, 'value' => 13],
];

$namearray = [];
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value) {
    $index = $value['number1'];
    $namearray[$index][] = $value['value'];
}
print_r($namearray);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 13
        )

)
```

Comment: it is possbile display ..Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3,10
            [1] => 3,13
            [2] => 11,0
        )

)

Comment: because array [1] length is 2 array[0] length is 3combine together and fill zero in the array?

Comment: This can't easy done in the loop. But, you can update the array, after the loop, because, you could know the final number of "number1". It could be another question. Does this anwser solve your current problem ?